# Similar option "-BSymbolic" for armlink

Tags: arm, dynamic-linking, relocation

To reduce the relocation, "-BSymbolic" *can* be used in gcc toolchain. But how about for the armlink ? is there similar option ?

Answer (score 0):

--symbolic from armlink. But it seems with different impl. with gcc.